# Java obtain image, check mime type, convert to png and return that image

Tags: java, image, return, mime-types

I'm trying to build a java servlet to obtain an image from an URL, check it's mime type and convert it if necessary, and then return that image.
What objects should I use, can you provide me some examples specially for obtaining the image and returning it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just use [JAI](https://jai.dev.java.net/) ([intro reference](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html)):

```
URL url = "// URL of the remote image to be read //";
RenderedImage original = JAI.create("url", url);
JAI.create("encode", original, response.getOutputStream(), "png");
```

Where `response` is an `HttpServletResponse`.  Note that checking the mime-type isn't needed, JAI will do what's necessary to figure out how to read the image under the covers.